# Disable/remove Cinnamon keyboard shortcurts

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, cinnamon

I installed Cinnamon on Ubunt 12.04 using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Now I am looking for a way to disable the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (move window) and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> (resize windows).

I already disabled those key bindings under *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts*. This doesn't have any effect.

I did not find them in `gconf-editor` under *Apps* → *Muffin*.

I already tried to disable them under *Apps* → *Metacity* → *global_keybindings* and *window_keybindings* which has no effect (although I thought Cinnamon uses Muffin and not Metacity).

How can I remove, edit, and disable those key bindings?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem. I've searched for 'F7' with the gconf-editor, but found nothing. I couldn't find anything in the dconf-editor, but that doesn't have a search function so I may have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question. It seems that in the current version of Cinnamon, you have a "Cinnamon Settings" menu entry. There you can adjust/disable the keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcuts can be found in gconf-editor, under `apps > metacity > global_keybindings and window_keybindings.`

Comment: I had those disabled as well. I thought `metacity` had no effect since cinnamon uses muffin so I didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: try to restart cinnamon

Comment: Even a full reboot of my system did not help. It seems the bindings are stored elsewhere